# How to add a line to multi dimensional hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, hash-of-hashes

I'm quite new to ruby and I'm blocking on this simple issue:

I have the following hash:

```
theData"=>{"586"=>{"status"=>"0"},
           "585"=>{"status"=>"0"}}
```

I would like to add a line "current_editor" at each level, to get the following hash:

```
theData"=>{"586"=>{"status"=>"0", "current_editor" => "3"},
           "585"=>{"status"=>"0", "current_editor" => "3"}}
```

How can I do this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theData = {"586"=>{"status"=>"0"}, "585"=>{"status"=>"0"}}
theData.each{|k, v| theData[k]["current_editor"] = 3}
#=> {"586"=>{"status"=>"0", "current_editor"=>3}, 
#=>  "585"=>{"status"=>"0", "current_editor"=>3}}
```